# find cell tower location in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, networking

Now I m trying to find the tower location using cellID, MNC,MCC and LAC. 
If you have the **cellId, MNC,MCC and LAC** then you can easily find the **cell tower location in iOS**. after some struggle i get the ans of this problem.

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own question, but you should put the answer in the "answer" section, not in the question itself.

Comment: from next time i will do @Paulw11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**now this is the ans of this question.**

```
#define google_geo_location @"https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key="
```

**google API LOCATION**

```
NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"google API key ",google_geo_location];
```

Create **JSON STRING**

```
NSString *json=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[{\"homeMobileCountryCode\": \"%@\",\"homeMobileNetworkCode\": \"%@\",\"cellTowers\": [{\"cellId\": \"%@\",\"locationAreaCode\": \"%@\",\"mobileCountryCode\": \"%@\",\"mobileNetworkCode\": \"%@\" }]}]",_mcctext,_mnctext,_cellidtext,_lactext,_mcctext,_mnctext];
```

convert **JSON STRING** in to **JSON DICTIONARY**

```
NSError *jsonError;
 NSData *objectData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSDictionary *jsondic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
```

**Create url from string**

```
NSURL *urlStr=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    if (urlStr == nil)
    {urlStr = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    }
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlStr];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

**set request body, If method type is "POST"**  use only **POST**

```
    NSData *data=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsondic options:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"jsonString.....%@",jsonString);
    NSData *requestBody = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// for set requestBody
[request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
```

**now you get response from server**

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];

    NSMutableDictionary *resultantDict;

    if (responseData != nil)
    {
        resultantDict=[NSJSONSerialization
                       JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                       error:nil];
        NSLog(@"resultantDict=%@",resultantDict);


        NSString *errorCode=@"";
        NSString *errorMessage=@"";
        if ([[resultantDict allKeys] containsObject:@"error"])
        {
            errorCode=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[resultantDict valueForKey:@"error"]valueForKey:@"code"]];
            errorMessage= [[resultantDict valueForKey:@"error"]valueForKey:@"message"];
        }


    }
```

Comment: how to get cell tower details? Does apple provides any api for that?